Should I use a single or multi-variable Runge-Kutta integrator to solve this ODE?
I have a 2nd order differential equation of the form: $$\frac{d^2 \Phi}{d \rho^2} + \frac{3}{\rho} \frac{d \Phi}{d \rho} = \Phi - \frac{3}{2} \Phi^2 + \frac{\alpha}{2} \Phi^3$$ with boundary conditions $\Phi(\infty) = \Phi_{fv}$ and $\frac{d \Phi}{d\rho}|_{\rho=0} = 0$. $\alpha$ here is simply a free variable. As far as I am aware, no analytic solutions exist so I have been trying to solve this numerically, specifically using 4th order Runge-Kutta integration. By defining $ u = \frac{d \Phi}{d\rho}$, this can be reduced to the system of equations : $$u = \frac{d \Phi}{d\rho}$$ and $$u'  = -  \frac{3}{\rho}u +\Phi - \frac{3}{2} \Phi^2 + \frac{\alpha}{2} \Phi^3 $$ I feel this is a basic question but should my initial point of integration by purely a function of $\rho$ or should I also include the field such that the initial point is $(\Phi(\rho), \rho)$. If it is both then what would my initial point be? Do I not have enough information to solve this? If it is purely $\rho$ then should I treat this as the x-variable or the t-variable in the tradition RK4 method? Sorry again for the simple question.

Ah I understand. Should my initial point be the scalar point 0, or the vector $(\Phi(0), 0)$ for Runge-Kutta integration?

$\rho$ is the independent variable. It is not updated by any of the complicated RK equations, just by $\rho_{i+1} = \rho_i + \Delta \rho$. You will update the 2-vector $(\Phi, \Phi')$ via the RK method.

I'm not sure precisely what you are asking, so apologize if this is too
simple. Consider it first as an initial value problem, since you are using
an RK solver. As is standard, you have split it into two first-order odes.
The first one is first order in $\Phi (\rho )$ and so you want an initial
condition giving a value for $\Phi (0)$. You will need to choose some value,
say $\Phi (0)=1$. The second one is first order in $u(\rho )$ and so needs
an initial condition giving a value for $u(0)$. Since you want $\left. \frac{
d\Phi }{d\rho }\right\vert _{\rho =0}=0$ and $u(\rho )=\frac{d\Phi }{d\rho },
$ you want $u(0)=0$. If you have a solver for a single first-order equation,
you can put it in a loop and take a step of the first equation, then a step
of the second equation with the updated value of $\Phi (\rho )$ and so on.
However most solvers are intended for a system of first order equations, and
they will update the two equations not only for each step in $\rho ,$ but
for the intermediate substeps of the RK algorithm.
Now you are actually wanting a boundary condition at infinity. So you can
adjust the initial value of $\Phi (0)$ until you get the value you want at
infinity (the shooting method). However, for initial values of the order of
1, the solution quickly goes to a constant that depends only on the value of
$\alpha $, e.g. for $\alpha =1/2,$ this is about $0.764$ and can be found as
follows. Note that for a constant, the left-hand side of your original ode
goes to zero. So the constant value will be the solution to the cubic
equation on the right-hand side, which is either zero or the two solutions
from the quadratic formula, one of which is $(3-\sqrt{9-8\alpha })/2\alpha $,
which gives the correct value for $\alpha =1/2$. That is, the final value
seems to be decoupled from the initial condition you choose. (For some other
initial values, e.g. for $\Phi (0)=6$ and $\alpha =1/2$, the
solution goes to infinity, so this only works over some range of initial
values.)
